# How would you save(append) data from one View Controller to another View Controller when you segue from a different view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

Sorry, the question is a bit long. Please bear with me.

Basically, I'm trying to write a simple count up/count down ios app using swift. I have three main view controllers. One is an "Initial View Controller" (which is the root view controller) that contain only two buttons - one that presents modally to the actual counting page (second view controller) and another present modally to a tableViewController page (third view controller). so those are the three view controllers.

So, if the user chooses to save the counter they have been counting I want to append the data on that counter view controller to an array I have created to be displayed on the tableViewController. So I'm making the tableViewController a delegate of the Counter View Controller to append the data to the array.

And as to my understanding, you need to implement prepareSegue in tableViewController to connect the tableViewController to the Counter View Controller. However, because the segue to the Counter View Controller doesn't originate from the tableViewController and instead from the Initial View Controller, the prepareSegue function is not working, and thus the delegate doesn't work. So to simplify my question- How would you save(append) data from one View Controller to another View Controller when you segue from a different view controller?

I hope my question was clear. I'm completely new to software development and not sure if I'm making any sense. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1 (Using Notifications):**

Each time the counter is updated in CounterViewController, the following code needs to be executed:

```
let notification = Notification.init(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UpdateCounter"), object: NSNumber.init(value: 1), userInfo: nil)    

NotificationCenter.default.post(notification)
```

This code is implemented in the Initial View Controller (to observe for the changes in counter):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(parseNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "UpdateCounter"), object: nil)
}

func parseNotification(_ notification: Notification?) {
    if let number = notification?.object as? NSNumber {
        /** here counter is a class variable in Initial ViewController **/
        counter = number.intValue
    }
}
```

And add the following code in **prepareforSegue** in the Initial View Controller

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    //Condition to check if TableViewController is being opened
    tableViewController.counter = counter
}
```

Don't forget to remove the observer in the Initial View Controller:

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

**Solution 2 (Using Global/Shared variables):**
Create a global/shared variable such as

```
class Shared {
    var value = 0
    let instance = Shared()
}
```

In the CounterViewController, you set the value every time the counter is updated

```
Shared.instance.value = counterValue
```

You can read the value in TableViewController using the following code:

```
Shared.instance.value
```

Comment: So if I would use the shared variable in the tableViewController class that contains an array and make changes(append) from another view controller using its shared variable like you’ve shown, would I be making changed to its original array or would I be creating another instance of an array? 
And please provide another solution so I know what else I can do to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: The shared value is in a separate class which can be used by any ViewController. In your case, you can set the value in CounterViewController each time the counter is changed and you can use this value in the TableViewController. I will edit my answer for another solution shortly.

Comment: @Alison.lwin Did this help?

Comment: Hi Nasir! sorry for the late response. I live in Asia, so I just woke up. I will try the notification method and see if it works.

Comment: Any updates? If this solved your issue maybe upvote the answer and select it as the solution

Comment: Hi! It took me a while to searched and understand both the solutions. Using Global/Shared Variable worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have three controllers in the storyboard path, One -> Two -> Three, and you want One to know about data changes in Three, then you need to propagate the changes via Two.

A rough version might look like this:

```
protocol CountDelegate: class {
    func updateCount()
}

class One: UIViewController, CountDelegate {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? Two else { return }
        destination.delegate = self
    }

    func updateCount() {
        // whatever
    }

}

class Two: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: CountDelegate?
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? Three else { return }
        destination.delegate = self.delegate // just pass the delegate down
    }
}

class Three: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: CountDelegate?

    func doWork() {
        self.delegate?.updateCount()
    }
}
```

So the delegate is One, and both Two and Three (via Two) point back to it as the delegate.

Comment: So using your example code above, (class one view controller segue to class two, and class two to three) I need class three to be the delegate and implement the func required to conform to the protocol (func updateCount() in your example), and class two to be pointing to class three as its delegate. So basically, after the prepareForSegue is performed in class one and class two view controller is loaded, I want class three (the class view controller coming up NEXT for the first time) to be the delegate of class two.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, you want the reverse. As I understood it, you want One (the Table view) to know about changes in Three (the Counter view). In that case, you want One to be the delegate of Three, with One implementing the updateCount function. In order to do this with Two in between, we have to pass a reference to One to Two, and then from Two to Three. Think of it like handing a passing a note in class. I give Shirley a note, and she gives it to you. Then you pass the note back to Shirley, and she passes it to me. I'm One, Shirley is Two, you are Three.

Comment: Yes, I want the reverse. So, I want three to know about the changes in Two as soon as three is loaded so it can implement any changes accordingly. Sorry if i'm being very confusing.