# How can I send data from FirstTableView to SecondTableView using Notification Center without segue

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsnotificationcenter

I have a problem when I try to pass an array from a UITableView to another one using NotificationCenter Design Pattern (because I don't have a segue between this 2 UIViewControllers). I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I don't receive any data in my second view controller.

My functions looks like this:

*** First VC - The Sender Controller (From where I send data) ***

```
class ProductsViewController: UIViewController{

var selectedProductsArray = [Product]()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)


        // Implement Notification Design Pattern to send data
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "productsToLoad"), object: selectedProductsArray)

        print(selectedProductsArray) // Here I have some data in this array (Photo here: https://ibb.co/k8hoEy)
    }
```

*** Second ViewController - The Receiver Controller (Where I will receive the data) ***

```
class CartViewController: UIViewController {

var productsInCartArray = [Product]()

 // We retrieve data from "selectedProductsArray" and we append all the products into "productsInCartArray"
    @objc func notificationRecevied(notification: Notification) {
        productsInCartArray = notification.object as! [Product]
        print(productsInCartArray)
    }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Add observer to watch when something was changed in "selectedProductsArray"
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notificationRecevied(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "productsToLoad"), object: nil)

       print(productsInCartArray) // Output: []

    }

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // We remove the observer from the memory
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "productsToLoad"), object: nil)
    }

}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Thank you for your time if you are reading this !

Comment: I have answered a similar questions @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/51006052/7280176

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove this from `viewWillDisappear` of `CartViewController`

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "productsToLoad"), object: nil)
```

as when you post in products the cards are not shown so there is no listener inside it , beside that `CartViewController` should be opened at least once before you post any data from `ProductsViewController`

//

you can completely remove the `NotificationCenter` work , and do this in `CartViewController`

```
let products = ((self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! ProductsViewController).selectedProductsArray
```

`Note :` Don't worry for `!` unwrapping it won't crash

Comment: Yes is exactly how you said. How can I fix this problem, because I don't want to navigate 2 times from FirstView to SecondView to see my data. Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Is not retrieving any data and is crashing when I click from SecondTab back to FirstTab with this error: "Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x10ffeff18) to 'ShoppingLand.ProductsViewController' (0x10d167668)."

Comment: Now is not crashing anymore but my secondArray("products") is empty and when I add 1 item in the cart then in my firstArray that item is added 2 times. So I add 1x iPhone X and I will have iPhoneX 2 times in my array.

Comment: Sorry I called your code in ViewWillDisappear...haha. Is working with just 1 line of code !!! Thank you so much for your time !!!

Comment: Happy coding =D